# Prepending WAV header to audio data of 16-bit unsigned integers

Tags: c++, wav

I am receiving an audio clip in form of 16-bit unsigned integers. I'd like to prepend a WAV header and save it into a file. I used [this](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) as my reference to hard code the header. (well, those parts that are fixed)

Here is my code for constructing the WAVE header:

```
std::string getWaveHeader(int data_size_bits, int channels, int sample_rate) {
    char header[] = 
    "RIFF"  // Chunk ID
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"  // Chunk size (not set)
    "WAVE"  // WAVE ID
    "fmt "  // Chunk ID
    "\x28\x00\x00\x00" // [little-endian] WAVE header size (40)
    "\xfe\xff"  // [little-endian] WAVE format code: WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE
    "\x00\x00"  // number of channels (not set)
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"  // sample rate (not set)
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"  // average bytes/sec (not set)
    "\x00\x00"  // block size (not set)
    "\x00\x00"  // bits per sample (not set)
    "\x16\x00"  // [little-endian] size of extension (22)
    "\x00\x00"  // valid bits (not set)
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"  // speaker position mask (not set)
    "\x03\x00\x00\x00"   // WAV_HEADER_SUB_FORMAT_CODE
    "\x00\x00\x10\x00"   // WAV_HEADER_SUB_GUID
    "\x80\x00\x00\xaa"   // WAV_HEADER_SUB_GUID
    "\x00\x38\x9b\x71"   // WAV_HEADER_SUB_GUID
    "fact"  // Chunk ID
    "\x04\x00"  // [little-endian] Chunk size (4)
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"  // dwSample Length (not set)
    "data"  // Chunk ID
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00";  // Wav header size (not set)

    // modifications on |header| ....
    // ...
    // Set the following params in little-endian using given information.
    // 1. Chunk size: |data_size_bits| + |header_size_bits| - 8
    // 2. number of channels (given)
    // 3. sample rate (given)
    // 4. average bytes/sec: |sample rate| * |bit_per_sample|/8 * |channels|
    // 5. block size: |bit_per_sample|/8 * |channels|
    // 6. bits per sample (given)
    // 7. valid bits: |bit_per_sample|
    // 8. Wav header size: |data_size_bits|

    std::string header_str = ConvertToString(header);

    return header_str;
}
```

I prepend the header to the byte array I receive and save it into a file. The saved output file doesn't seem to have all the right meta info in its header and I was wondering if I'm using the right header and parameters for my case.

My reference: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

Comment: How does the caller know how long the header is?  You're returning a character pointer, which will contain embedded nul bytes.  Better would be to declare a struct/class to hold the header.  The format chunk id is `fmt ` (note the trailing space).

Comment: How can you even return a local array like that? I'm pretty sure that would lead you to all 7 hells of bad behaviour..

Comment: First, that array is ugly and lethal. Second, have you heard of structs? They are quite lovely and give you the ability to customize values in a complex data structure.

Comment: Thank y'all for the help regarding the array/struct point. I get that. However, this is just a part of the code and I simplified it so it's easier to check the issue. I updated the function to return std::string just to avoid distracting readers from the main point of the question; i.e., checking whether there's anything wrong with the header.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, but there are a zillion details that could trip you up.  If you're on Windows, you might consider using the multimedia i/o library (e.g., mmioOpen and friends) to do the file handling just to eliminate the possibility of stupid mistakes there.  Or, you could use the mmio library to try reading the file you produced to check its format.  Also, if you just have PCM data, I'd use WAVE_FORMAT_PCM instead of WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE, which just adds complexity for features you're apparently not using.

Comment: Last item in the "header" is the data chunk size, not the wave header size (as the comment suggests).  Also, that size is in bytes, not bits, as comment 8 says in the modifications section.

Comment: One last thing.  Check the byte order of the GUID very carefully.  (It looks like you're trying to use KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT.)  Some things treat GUIDs as 16 bytes; others treat them as a struct containing a variety of sizes.  I'd find a working WAVE file with that format and compare your GUID to that one.

Comment: Your last comment was the problem I had and the other two comments are also nice practices - why not write them as an answer? Would the header be the same if I use FLAC encoding?